# How to reduce vertex count on a mesh

Tags: mesh, vertices, 3d-printing

I need a way to fix this mesh.
It has way too many faces and when I import the `.stl` file to other programs it gives me a `broken polygon` message. I want to 3D print this object in matter control once I fix the problem.

[image]

Comment: Try the decimate modifier

Comment: My guess is that you don't have too many faces, but actually you have non manifold geometry.  Try using the re-mesh modifier with a high settings.  This should fix your objects and make them water tight again

Answer (score 72):

Select all vertices, hit <kbd>X</kbd> button and select **Limited Dissolve** from the menu.

[image]

Then hit <kbd>F6</kbd> button and adjust **Maximum Angle** to get desired result.

[image]

Then to triangulate the mesh hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut.

Answer (score 34):

The easiest way to reduce the vertex count on a model is probably to use the *Decimate modifier*. Basically it tries to simplify a mesh, without loosing too much detail. There are also multiple modes, for finer control, but the default one should do for most cases.

What you need to do is, with your object selected, to go to the *modifier* tab of the *Properties* window and add a *Decimate* modifier. I encourage you to play around with the multiple settings and modes to see which best suits your needs.

Comment: I have the best luck with using the "Planar" setting with the Decimate modifier.  Play with the angle to see how it affects your shape.  The modifier even displays the face count which is really cool.

Comment: This should be the answer. It's non-destructive and hardly alters the object shape. You also get fine grained control over how many faces to reduce by via the `ratio` input on the modifier.