# How do i get rid of my vertices and make my model just a blank model

Tags: modeling, vertices

I want to know how i can make my model just a blank model with no vertices so that it will be easier for me to create other parts. i already checked this tread and it didnt help:[Is there an unsubdivide function in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21082/is-there-an-unsubdivide-function-in-blender)

Here is a pic of what it looks like right now:[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93314/how-do-you-decrease-the-amount-of-vertices-in-an-object https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/188067/how-to-decrease-the-poly-count-in-blender https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31467/how-to-reduce-vertex-count-on-a-mesh/

Comment: Q title suggests: edit mode A (select all) X (delete) choose vertices leaving you with _"just a blank model"_.

Comment: "*i already checked this tread and it didnt help*" Why not? What did you try and how did it fail?